# Do we want anonymity?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

The [anonymity](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/anonymity) tag currently has no description and just 9 questions. Is that a useful tag, and if so, which questions is it appropriate for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would burn it, I cant see a professional use of that tag.

To compare, on Information Security that tag is used 289 times, and its a better site suited for that tag in my own opinion.

Comment: Done! There shouldn't be any linked questions anymore and that ought to make the tag disappear after a while.

Comment: @HBruijn The tag is now completely gone.